# Symfony 4: обновление ролей

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: когда изменяю права/роли у пользователя, то ему необходимо перезайти в свой аккаунт, чтобы они обновились. Можно ли как-то избавиться от этой неприятной особенности?

Comment: Возможно, Вам нужно удалить сессию пользователя, вручную разлогинить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании стандартной аутентификации данные пользователя сериализуются и сохраняются в сессии. Далее при каждом запросе обращение к БД не происходит, а данные берутся из сессии. Если вам надо постоянно контролировать изменения, связанные с пользователем, то можете написать собственный аутентикатор https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html в котором можете перечитывать данные пользователя из БД при каждом запросе https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#avoid-authenticating-the-browser-on-every-request

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, нет. Конфигурация считывается при заходе в аккаунт, и не может изменяться без перезахода - что совершенно правильно и обосновано.